# Take the elemnt in strsplit and put to dataFrame

Tags: regex, r, split

I split a string based on `_`.

I added the output straight to the data frame I have. However, now my second column has a vector of each split string in it.

Example code:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5, 6) 
s = c("DUMMY_PO0111385745_TEST_LLN_DOLHTM", "DUMMY_VO0111385745_ST_LdN_DOLHTM", "DUMMY_PO0143385745_TE_N_CHHTM", "DUMMY_US0121785745_TEST1_MM_EURHTM") 
df = data.frame(n, s) 

# convert all factors to character strings
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
df$ID_NUMB <- strsplit(df$s, "_", fixed=TRUE)
```

Any recommendation on how to just take the "number" out of the split vector, for example: `PO0111385745`?

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: You could have used `df <- data.frame(n,s, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: Using your method you could do probably `df$ID_NUMB <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$s, "_", fixed=TRUE), "[[", 2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
library(stringr)
df$s1 <- str_extract(df$s,'\\d+')
df$s1
#[1] "0111385745" "0111385745" "0143385745" "0121785745"
```

Or a base R option

```
gsub("[^0-9]+", '', df$s)
#[1] "0111385745"  "0111385745"  "0143385745"  "01217857451"
```

If you need the letters as well

```
 gsub(".*?([A-Z]+[0-9]+).*", '\\1', df$s)
 #[1] "PO0111385745" "VO0111385745" "PO0143385745" "US0121785745"
```